# How to provide dynamic server variables to browserify module?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, browserify

I have an equivalent example in require.js where I need to supply dynamic server variables. How do I do this with browserify?

```
<script>require(['modules/headerNav'], function(headerNav){
  headerNav({
    /*server side variables here */
    fruit:'apple',
    size:'large',
    type:'empire'
  });
});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have answered my own question:

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  var through = require('through');
  var duplexer = require('duplexer');
  var myModule = require('my-module');
  /* ... */
myModule({/* dynamic server variables here...*/});
</script>
```